# How to calculate or show in matlab/pspice the DC component from a circuit simulation?

Tags: dc, simulation, spice, matlab, pspice

Based on Pspice I'm simulating this RL full wave rectifier
[image]

That gives the next voltage and current output at the showed probe point
[image]
[image]

The idea is to extract the DC component of the current or voltage, but I don't know how to this (be in pspice or matlab).

From the matlab approach, I export the simulation as csv, open inside matlab launch the pid tuner program and load the data, then fit and get this one
[image]
and the next model of the plant
[image]

But whats next? I don't know if the FFT apply here since this is not a frequency analysis.

Comment: Cant you just calculate the average of the dataset?

Comment: @Linkyyy, Indeed I think this is the short response, but I was told to do this way..even though dont see the benefit of it.